# How Do I Find The Owning Assembly Of An Object In C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to do some processing on all assemblies that own forms that are currently open in my application.  I can easily get the form objects with:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms
```

I want to iterate through this list and find the owning assembly for each instance.  I know how to find the assembly that owns a given form class, but not a specific class instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
formInstance.GetType().Assembly
```

**Edit in response to comment:**

```
from form in Application.OpenForms
where form.Owner != null
select form.Owner.GetType().Assembly
```

Comment: No, as I was saying above, that finds the Assembly owning the class Type.  I want the assembly where formInstance is owned.

Comment: It sounds like you want the assembly containing the `Form` class corresponding to the `.Owner` property of each instance in `OpenForms`. Is that correct? I have updated my answer to reflect my new understanding. I was confused because you said "I want to iterate through this list [OpenForms] and find the owning assembly for each instance." "Owning assembly" implies the assembly in which the form is declared, not the assembly of its owner. I think you meant "I want to iterate through this list and find the assembly of the owner of each instance." Let me know if that's right.

Comment: I didn't realize that's what I wanted, but now that you've put that code in front of me, yes, that's the answer I was looking for.